# Good practice to tag resources with bulk list of array

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sdk

We have a scenario, where we need to tag with 4 tags' key value pair for a large list of snapshots. While we traverse the list of snapshots for this also some check would be present to do checks on already present snapshots.

Now what I can tag them with create_tags command, I fear due to API call it may fail in between and the tagging may remain incomplete. What is the good way to tag resources in such cases with minimizing risk of failure?

I am using aws-sdk for ruby.

Comment: What is the basis of your "fear"? If it fails, could the Ruby script simply restart and tag the remaining untagged instances? Also, you might be interested in [Working with Tag Editor - AWS Management Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/tag-editor.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
In my case if the script breaks due to API call, on incomplete tagging operation it may cause in consistent tagging on few snapshots, upon which the checks are put before tagging. So on failure, the logic of script may stand redundant.

That's why I was curious in knowing a good way to ensure it goes in one shot on tagging about 2000 resource.

Comment: Processing the records in chunks is a good idea, such as using [in_groups_of](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) or [find_in_batches](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches). And for each batch you can perform a bulk update, such as with the [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem. You can tweak around the batch size, it's a balance between the size of each query and the number of queries. And then you can use rescue to implement some retry logic.